# How to implement Lazy Chain Pattern in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am trying to define a set of "LazyChains" that will be used to process incoming messages at a future time. I want the API of the LazyChains to be indistinguishable from the Scala collections APIs (ie: Seq, Stream, etc). This would allow me to declaratively define filtering/transformations/actions ahead of time before the messages arrive. It's possible that this is a well known pattern that I don't know the name of, so that is making it hard for me to find any results on this.

This is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
val chainA = LazyChain()
 .filter(_ > 1)
 .map(x => x * 2)
 .foreach(println _)

val chainB = LazyChain()
 .filter(_ > 5)
 .flatMap(x => Seq(x, x))
 .foreach(println _)

 chainA.apply(2)  // should print "4"
 chainA.apply(1)  // should print nothing
 chainB.apply(10) // should print "10" - twice
```

Does this pattern already exist in the Scala collections API? If not, how can I implement this class `LazyChain`?

This is my current attempt at this. I can't seem to work out how to get the types to work:

```
case class LazyChain[I, O](val filter : Option[I => Boolean],
                      val transform : I => O,
                      val action : Option[O => Unit]) {

  def filter(otherFilter : I => Boolean): LazyChain[I, O]  = {
      val newFilter = Some({ x : I => {
        filter.map(_.apply(x)).getOrElse(true) && otherFilter.apply(x)
      }})
      copy(filter = newFilter)
  }

  def map[X](otherTransform : O => X) : LazyChain[I, X] = {
    new LazyChain[I, X](
      filter = filter,
      transform = (x: I) => {
        otherTransform.apply(transform.apply(x))
      },
      /*
        type mismatch;
        [error]  found   : Option[O => Unit]
        [error]  required: Option[X => Unit]
      */
      action = action 
    )
  }

  def flatMap[X](otherTransform : O => Seq[X]) : LazyChain[I, X] = {
    new LazyChain[I, X](
      filter = filter,
      transform = (x: I) => {
        /**
           type mismatch;
             [error]  found   : Seq[X]
             [error]  required: X
        */
        otherTransform.apply(transform.apply(x))
      }
    )
  }

  def foreach(newAction : O => Unit) = {
    copy(action = Some(newAction))
  }

  def apply(element : I) = {
    if (filter.map(_.apply(element)).getOrElse(true)) {
      val postTransform = transform.apply(element)
      action.foreach(_.apply(postTransform))
    }
  }
}
object LazyChain {
  def apply[X]() : LazyChain[X, X] = {
    new LazyChain(filter = None, transform = x => x, action = None)
  }
}
```

Comment: Scala has [Views](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/views.html) which transform any collection in a lazy collection. Maybe there are some helpful hints there

Comment: `akka-streams` will allow you to do this. But it might be too "heavy" for you

Comment: Iteratees let you do stuff like this pretty naturally: you can build up transformations (_enumeratees_) and plug them into sources (_enumerators_) and sinks (_iteratees_), and these are all just values.

Comment: (Full disclosure: I maintain [an iteratee library for Scala](https://meta.plasm.us/posts/2016/01/08/yet-another-iteratee-library/).)

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions guys. I will take a look at all three. I'm mainly interested in a lightweight solution that I could implement myself (also for my own knowledge). I'm sure I will learn by looking at the implementation of those libraries.

Comment: A faster alternative to akka-streams is [Monix](https://monix.io/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you want is to wrap a function `I => List[O]` with some fancy methods. You could write your `implicit class` to add these methods to this type, but Kleisli does most of this for free, via various cats type classes, mainly `FilterFunctor`.

```
  import cats.implicits._
  import cats.data.Kleisli

  type LazyChain[I, O] = Kleisli[List, I, O]
  def lazyChain[A]: LazyChain[A, A] = Kleisli[List, A, A](a => List(a))

  val chainA = lazyChain[Int]
    .filter(_ > 1)
    .map(x => x * 2)
    .map(println)

  val chainB = lazyChain[Int]
    .filter(_ > 5)
    .flatMapF(x => List(x, x))
    .map(println)

  chainA(2)  // should print "4"
  chainA(1)  // should print nothing
  chainB(10) // should print "10" - twice
```

It might look a bit too magical, so here is a handmade version:

```
case class LazyChain[A, B](run: A => List[B]) {

  def filter(f: B => Boolean): LazyChain[A, B] = chain(_.filter(f))

  def map[C](f: B => C): LazyChain[A, C] = chain(_.map(f))

  def flatMap[C](f: B => List[C]): LazyChain[A, C] = chain(_.flatMap(f))

  def chain[C](f: List[B] => List[C]): LazyChain[A, C] = LazyChain(run andThen f)
}
object LazyChain {
  def apply[I]: LazyChain[I, I] = new LazyChain(a => List(a))
}
```

Chaining transformations is a common concern and, as the comments say, using something like monix.Observable, iteratees, etc is the proper way to approach this problem (rather than a plain `List` and streams are naturally lazy.